# PHP array_push() error 'array expected'

Tags: php

1. Quiero pasar la el valor en la posición '$array[$j]' a '$arrayComun'
2. Me da el error de:

> Expected parameter of type 'array', 'string' provided

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
    $array2 = array('d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h');
    $arrayComun = array();
    $arrayNoComun = array();
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($array2); $j++) {
            if ($array1[$i] == $array2[$j]) {
                echo 'Común:  Array ( '. $array2[$j] . ')';
                array_push($array2[$j], $arrayComun);
                echo '<br>';
            } else {
                echo 'No Común:  Array ( '. $array2[$j] . ')';
                echo '<br>';
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres lograr. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado final esperado?

Comment: Quiero recorrer los dos arrays comparandolos entre ellos, los elementos que tengan en común ponerlos en '$arrayComun' y los no comunes en $arrayNoComun'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es meter en `$arrayComun` el valor de `$array2[$j]` cuando se cumple el `if`, basta con que hagas esto:

```
$arrayComun[]=$array2[$j];
```

O bien con [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php), pero cambiando los parámetros, primero debes pasar el array y luego el valor:

```
array_push($arrayComun,$array2[$j]);
```

Y lo mismo para no común.

Entonces, tu código puede quedar así simplemente:

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$array2 = array('d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h');
$arrayComun = array();
$arrayNoComun = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($array2); $j++) {
        if ($array1[$i] == $array2[$j]) {
            array_push($arrayComun,$array2[$j]);
            echo 'Común:  Array ( '. $array2[$j] . ')';
            echo '<br>';
        } else {
            array_push($arrayNoComun,$array2[$j]);
            echo 'No Común:  Array ( '. $array2[$j] . ')';
            echo '<br>';
        }

    }
}
```

También puedes hacerlo así, sin `array_push()`:

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$array2 = array('d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h');
$arrayComun = array();
$arrayNoComun = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($array2); $j++) {
        if ($array1[$i] == $array2[$j]) {
            $arrayComun[]=$array2[$j];
            echo 'Común:  Array ( '. $array2[$j] . ')';
            echo '<br>';
        } else {
            $arrayNoComun[]=$array2[$j];
            echo 'No Común:  Array ( '. $array2[$j] . ')';
            echo '<br>';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!